# displaying search result of database stored images without file extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have an autocomplete search box that culled up the thumbnail of images stored in the database. The problem is that the .jpg extension shows up each times the image name appears in the autocomplete search box. Is there anyway I can modify these codes to prevent the .jpg extension from appearing? Below is my existing code using javascript and ashx.
Thank you in advance!

the aspx:

```
<script src="scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="scripts/jquery.autocomplete.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#<%=txtSearch.ClientID%>").autocomplete("Search.ashx", {
                width: 200,
                formatItem: function (data, i, n, value) {
                    return "<img style = 'width:50px;height:50px' src= 'Images/" + value.split(",")[1] + "'/> " + value.split(",")[0];
                },
                formatResult: function (data, value) {
                    return value.split(",")[0];
                }
            });
        });
</script>

<style type="text/css">
    .Gridview {
        font-family: Verdana;
        font-size: 10pt;
        font-weight: normal;
        color: black;
    }
</style>
</head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <div>
                Search here: 
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtSearch" runat="server" />
                <br />
            </div>

            <div>
                <asp:FileUpload ID="fileuploadimages" runat="server" />
                <br />
                <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" />
            </div>
            <div>
            </div>
            <asp:Label ID="lblResult" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

the ashx:

```
public class Search : IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        string searchText = context.Request.QueryString["q"];
        string strcon = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbconnection"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(strcon);
        connection.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select ID,ImageName,ImagePath from ImagesPath where ImageName Like @Search + '%'", connection);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Search", searchText);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                sb.Append(string.Format("{0},{1}{2}", dr["ImageName"], dr["ImageName"], Environment.NewLine));
            }
        }
        connection.Close();
        context.Response.Write(sb.ToString());
    }
    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do a search and replace, either in the ashx

```
dr["ImageName"].ToString().Replace(".jpg", "");
```

Or in the database

```
select ID, REPLACE(ImageName, '.jpg', '') AS ImageName, ImagePath from ImagesPath
```

Or if you have more than one extension, you can also do this

```
Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(dr["ImageName"].ToString())
```

This filters out the extension of every file, and the path should it be present:

```
string file = @"c:\folder\testFile.jpg";
string result = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file);

//result: testFile
```

Translated to your snippet it would look something like this.

```
while (dr.Read())
{
    string file = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(dr["ImageName"].ToString());
    sb.Append(string.Format("{0},{1}{2}", file, file, Environment.NewLine));
}
```

Comment: Thanks VDWWD The first option worked. But for multiple extensions like .jpg, .png, .gif , how do I implement the GetFileNameWithoutExtension considering my Images are stored in the db?

Comment: Updated my answer to afust it to your snippet.

Comment: Thanks for the update, VDWWD. Again "Path" is underlined with the message "The name Path does not exist in the current context".

Comment: Add `using System.IO;` in code behind. Tip: setting the mouse cursor on `Path` and clicking `Ctrl` + `.` together in Visual Studio will suggest this.

Comment: Thanks. Finally, It is fine now. I commend your prompt response. You are a life saver!

Comment: I was wondering if it is achievable to have the search result displayed on a model view. I have asked this question under a different heading "Displaying search result using Model view"